# How can I add a class to every 1st, 4th, 5th, 8th, 9th, 12th, 13th

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a class to these elements via js to alter a masonic layout.

How can this be done without specifying the pattern manually?

Thanks

The pattern is this:

1st = class
2nd
3rd
4th = class
5th = class
6th
7th
8th = class
9th = class
10th
11th
12th = class
13th = class
etc.

Codepen attempt: https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/EvWbGe?editors=1010

```
$('.touch').each(function(index) {

    if ( index === 0 || index % 3 ) {

        $(this).addClass('touched');
    }
});
```

Comment: Share your current code for more info

Comment: Given your reputation, I believe, you understand that you need to share the relevant code to understand the question. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question and learn why you are receiving downvotes

Comment: start with number 0(zero) after you add +1 then +3 and +1 and +3, so on. you get the idea, not so hard.

Comment: So what is the pattern?

Comment: I added the pattern i need

Comment: Pattern added, code added, codepen added, how can I do what I need please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way in pure CSS

```
.touch:first-of-type, .touch:nth-of-type(4n), .touch:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.touch').each(function(index) {

    if ( index  % 4 == 0 || index  % 4 == 3  ) {

        $(this).addClass('touched');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for this. there's a pure CSS solution where you use two classes both using [`nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/).

```
.pattern li:nth-child(4n),
.pattern li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: lightsteelblue;
}
```

See this [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brqYOw) (modified form the above article) for an example.

Here is a picture of the result:

[image: list of elements with highlighting in line with Origina lposters requirements]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it here is the pattern:

```
$('.touch').each(function(index) {

    if ( index % 4 == 0 || (index + 1) % 4 == 0 ) {

        $(this).addClass('touched');
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/EvWbGe?editors=1010